# Are there downsides to enabling the "inline data" feature of EXT4?

Tags: ext4

I just read [about the "inline data" feature in EXT4](https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Disk_Layout#Inline_Data), and more specifically [about that answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/197633/how-to-use-the-new-ext4-inline-data-feature-storing-data-directly-in-the-inode/197806#197806) on how to enable it.

What are the reasons why this feature isn't enabled by default in EXT4 ? I guess it's to keep the FS compatible with older kernels, that didn't support this feature yet. Are there other reasons ?

If I know that I'll never use an older kernel, is there any reason NOT to always enable this feature when formatting a partition with EXT4 ?

Comment: Doesn't look like the 2013 patch to  add support for `grub` has been merged yet, so  you probably don't want to enable it on the /boot FS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question, basically just developing Stéphane Chazelas' comment :

As Theodore Ts'o ([maintainer of ext4](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/MAINTAINERS?id=1f719a2f3fa67665578c759ac34fd3d3690c1a20#n7990)) explained in [an e-mail dating back to 2019](https://lkml.kernel.org/linux-ext4/20190914232801.GD19710@mit.edu/T):

> There are some known issues with with the inline_data feature (...).
>
> (...)
>
> But yeah, there is a good reason why it's not a default-enabled
> feature.  It also generally doesn't buy you much for most file system
> workloads, so it hasn't been high on my priority list to fix.

So it's probably best no to enable that feature for now, unless absolutely needed.

Comment: There have been quite a few fixes since 2019, including to inline data, but I haven’t seen any more recent update on the actual situation of inline data support.